# Davies-boudin index and maximum ratio

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

Davies-bouldin index validation is basically the ratio within cluster scatter and between cluster distances. We iterate that for all clusters and finally take the `maximum`. My question here is why maximum not minimum?

Thank you.

Comment: Why minimum and not maximum?!?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse based on Wiki [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davies–Bouldin_index) it should be the max !!

Comment: Yes. So why the minimum, if it is defined to be the maximum? It's a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following scenario:

Three clusters. One is well separated from the others, two are conflated.

Let S_i be 0.5 for all of them.

For the conflated ones, M_ij is close to zero. For the well separated ones, the distance of the means is much larger. The resulting R_i is large for the conflated ones, and small for the separated clusters.

If you take the maximum, the index says "two clusters are mixed up, the result is thus bad - not all clusters are well separated". If you used the minimum, it would ignore this problem and say "well, at least it separated them from *one* of the other clusters".

Comment: Thank you so much. Well explained :)